# im getting this error 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in new to flutter

Tags: flutter

```
 final extractedData = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map <String, dynamic>;
```

my result in the back end
flutter:

```
[{_id: 626f87577313d0f0078855cd, number: 9952533323, amount: 1000, date: 9952533323, __v: 0}, {_id: 626f93cb7313d0f0078855d2, number: 9952533321, amount: 100, date: 9952533321, __v: 0}]
```

and my error is:

```
'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

Answer (score 0):

it simply isn't a Map, it's a List of Maps so just change it to

```
final extractedData = jsonDecode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
```

and then the first item is for example

```
final first = extractedData[0] as Map<String, dynamic>;
```